# Sqlalchemy many to many mapping with extra fields

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I created a many to many relationship with sqlalchemy like this:

```
subject_books = Table('subject_books', Base.metadata,
    Column('subject_id', Integer, ForeignKey('subjects.id')),
    Column('book_id', Integer, ForeignKey('books.id')),
    Column('group', Integer)
)

class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(255))
    isbn = Column(Unicode(24))
    subjects = relationship('Subject', secondary=subject_books, collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('group'), backref='books')
```

after that I created a test like following:

```
book = Book(title='first book',isbn='test')
book.subjects[0] = Subject(value='first subject')
book.subjects[1] = Subject(value='second subject')

session.add(book)
transaction.commit()
```

and it works fine. But what I really want is to store more than one subject with the same **group** value, so I tried the following test:

```
book = Book(title='first book',isbn='test')
book.subjects[0] = [Subject(value='first subject'),Subject(value='second subject')]
book.subjects[1] = [Subject(value='third subject'),Subject(value='forth subject')]

session.add(book)
transaction.commit()
```

but it does not work.

Can this be done using sqlalchemy?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think the model you have is represented well on the DB level. But the simple way of working with as you wish... I am not sure of out-of-the-box solution, but you might try to implement your own Custom Collection (see http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/collections.html?highlight=attribute_mapped_collection#custom-collection-implementations)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Razi

I think you are constructing wrong relation ship.

Your relation ship must be

**book M2M subject**

**subject M2M group**

So you have to create one more model for group and that must be assign as `m2m` in Subject

Your models will be like.

```
subject_books = Table('subject_books', Base.metadata,
    Column('subject_id', Integer, ForeignKey('subjects.id')),
    Column('book_id', Integer, ForeignKey('books.id')),        
)
subject_group = Table('subject_groups', Base.metadata,
    Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id')),
    Column('subject_id', Integer, ForeignKey('subjects.id')),
)

class Subject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'subjects'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)
    groups = relationship('Groups', secondary=subject_groups, backref='subjects')

class Groups(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)

class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id =  Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(255))
    isbn = Column(Unicode(24))
    subjects = relationship('Subject', secondary=subject_books, backref='books')
```

I also check the docs for [attribute_mapped_collection](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/search.html?q=attribute_mapped_collection&check_keywords=yes&area=default). But each time I found that each key is associated with only one object not more then one. If you read anywhere then please provide the link so I can check that how it will be fit in your code.

I think this will be help you.